# Start the NFC tag only from my specific application

Tags: android, nfc

I am just completed the NFC based application. In this I am simply scanning the NFC tag and fetching the serial number of the NFC.

But When NFC tag comes near across the device, then it show all the application list which can scan the NFC tag where there I can set by doing "Always" or "default" but I want this do somehow programmatically.

I am looking for this because it seems to bug in some devices that not working as it seems.

Bug in the devices : I have two devices that is not showing even "Always" or "default as action" in the dialog box when NFC tag come near across the device.

See the screenshot :

[image: Screenshot]

```
<activity
    android:name="net.livepatrols.thepartnerSA.NFCActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

NFCActivity.java

```
public class NFCActivity extends Activity {

    private NfcAdapter mNFCAdapter;
    private PendingIntent mNfcPendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc);

        // Create the OpenSqliteHelper object. It always best to create only
        // once instance of this OpenSqliteHelper
        DatabaseManager.init(this);

        mNFCAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        if (mNFCAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support NFC
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    getString(R.string.device_does_not_support_nfc),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (!mNFCAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                // NFC is disabled
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.enable_nfc),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(NFCActivity.this,
                        0, new Intent(NFCActivity.this, NFCActivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mNFCAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            mNFCAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcPendingIntent, null,
                    null);
            Tag mTag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

            byte byteId[] = mTag.getId();

            int size = byteId.length;
            // Convert the byte array to integer
            String str = "";
            if (size > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    byte myByte = byteId[i];
                    int myInt = (int) (myByte & 0xFF);
                    str += myInt;
                }
            }

            SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyyMMddhhmmss");

            SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            boolean mRegistrationStatus = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(
                    "registration_status", false);
            boolean mExpiredStatus = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(
                    "expire_status", true);

            Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

            if (mRegistrationStatus && !mExpiredStatus) {

                // Tag here started to scan the the NFC tags
                mEditor.putString("message", "Tag Read in");
                mEditor.commit();

                if (Util.isDeviceConnectedWithInternet(this)) {
                    // Upload the NFC details.

                    // Start the service and send the NFC Tag Info in the
                    // intent.
                    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,
                            UploadNFCTagInfoService.class);

                    serviceIntent.putExtra("mNFCSerialNumber", str);
                    serviceIntent.putExtra("mNFCScannedTimeStamp",
                            mSimpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));
                    startService(serviceIntent);

                } else {

                    // Device is not connected with the Internet.
                    // Store the NFC Tag details in the SQLite database.
                    // When device connect with Internet later then
                    // these records will be uploaded on the database server.

                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.network_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    mEditor.putString("message", "Tag has been saved in the application database to upload it later if your device is activated");
                    mEditor.commit();

                    NFCIItem mNFCItem = new NFCIItem();
                    mNFCItem.setSerialNumber(str);
                    mNFCItem.setScanTimeStamp(mSimpleDateFormat
                            .format(new Date()));

                    // Insert the record in the database.
                    DatabaseManager.getInstance().addNFCTag(mNFCItem);

                }
            } else if(!mRegistrationStatus) {
                mEditor.putString("message", "Device is not activated to scan NFC Tags");
                mEditor.commit();
            }
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I know how to solve this issue is to add an additional [AAR record](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar) (special NDEF record) on your tag. Subsequently, only your app is starting and nobody is asking anymore.

Comment: Oh, I do not want to write the data in the NFC tag first

Comment: Then, if no intent filtering is possible, there is no way to avoid the selection of an application, except only one app is available.

Comment: Any option such that to remember the app like "Always" ?

Comment: No. I have been through that issue, too. Maybe in future releases, but I guess that is some security feature.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48230/discussion-between-williams-and-pizzaani)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If the app is open, you can use foreground dispatch to make your app the preferred one (which you seem to already be using). Best you can do is tune your NFC tech filter to match the tag as best as possible (tech+NDEF, etc.). As for devices that don't show the 'Always' option, what happens if double-tap the app in the dialog?

Comment: If I double tap the app in the dialog then again it is asking to further scans

Comment: but why this issue that it does not have any option to remember like which commonly all devices have, I tested this app in two devices and both I did not find that options

Comment: This is probably due to some vendor customization, you just have to live with it.

Comment: Then any thing alternative that can remember the action?